# How to get sharepoint list data into csv using Python?

Tags: python, rest, csv, sharepoint

I am using following python script to export sharepoint list into csv.

```
 `
from sharepoint import SharePointSite, basic_auth_opener

server_url = "https://sps16.com/sites/Url/"
site_url = server_url + "/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx?wsdl"
opener = basic_auth_opener(server_url, "domain\username", "password")
site = SharePointSite(site_url, opener)
for sp_list in site.lists:
print (sp_list.id, sp_list.meta['2016 App Scan'])`
```

It gives me this  errror : `urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:579)>`

how to make SSL certificate validation false.?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add authentication in response header:

```
`import requests
from requests_ntlm import HttpNtlmAuth

auth = HttpNtlmAuth('username','pass')

r = requests.get(
"https://sps16.com/sites/url/",
verify=False,
auth=auth,
headers={
'Accept': "application/json",
}

)
#print (r.json())
print (r.status_code)
print (r.headers)`
```